# error unable to open database file in Sqlite3 Scripts

Tags: sqlite

hii I am novice to Sqlite3.
i wrote a script for database connection. It showed some error. 
is their any way to alter that script and execute it again or i have to write whole script again(that will not be a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

Easy, if you have access to the command line on your system, e.g., the "DOS box" on MS-Windows, the konsole program on KDE linux or the terminal program on GNOME linux.

Write your SQL statements into a file with the editor of your choice. Do NOT use any "funny characters" like German Umlaute or French accents in this file. 
N.B.: Please terminate each SQL statement with a semi-colon, e.g.,

```
    SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

You can also use all commands into this file which are displayed when you run just

```
    sqlite3
```

and then enter ".help" at the sqlite prompt:

```
    SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
    Enter ".help" for instructions
    Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
    sqlite> .help
```

Now you have basically 2 ways to run this set of SQL statements with SQLite3:

a) Test your code with a temporary database generated ad-hoc in memory:
N.B.: This temporary database will be automatically deleted at the end of your SQL statements.
So you need to include your 'CREATE table' and 'INSERT INTO table' statements in this file.

```
    sqlite3 < yourfile.sql
```

b) Run your code against a file-based SQLite database for repeated usage:

```
    sqlite3 /path/to/your/databasefile.sqlite < yourfile.sql
```

If 'databasefile.sqlite' does not yet exist it will be automatically created. If you don't like the current version of 'databasefile.sqlite' just delete it and rerun your set of SQL statements at shown above.

AFAIK you can give your 'databasefile.sqlite' any name which is allowed on your system. Nevertheless, the convention is that the database filename's extension is '.sqlite''

HTH

bernie